# Sort by integer leaves out last element of array C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I am new to C++ and I'm making a sorting algorithm to sort a list of structs by a certain integer value (ID in this very case); The sorting mechanism works just fine but leaves out the last element of the array in it's place and I really don't understand why. The list is in this order (130, 121, 140, 170, 120, 133) and this is the code:

'''

```
class List{
    private:
        Step* head;
        Aisle* first;
        int size...
```

...

```
struct Step{
    Articolo info;
    Step* next;
    Step(Articolo to_push){this->info=to_push; this->next=NULL;};
};

struct Articolo{
    int ID;
    string name;
    int quantity;
    int aisle;
    float price;
};

void List::printCode(){
    Articolo temp_list[this->size];
    Step* temp = this->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){           // this whole part is to copy my dinamic list in an array, making it easier to re-arrange;
        temp_list[i] = temp->info;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    Articolo lowest = temp_list[0];                 // i set the lowest element as the first element
    for (int j=1; j < (this->size); j++){           // and start the sorting from the second element 
        if (lowest.ID > temp_list[j].ID){
            lowest = temp_list[j];
            for (int k = j; k > 0; k--){            // this is the sorting part
                temp_list[k] = temp_list[k-1];
            }
            temp_list[0] = lowest;
        }
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < this->size; z++){
        printInfo(temp_list[z]);                    // it's just a function for printing the info of an Article type variable;
    }
}
```

'''

And this is the output:

```
Codice: -1173245000; Nome: ���`����k�`������������ats����`���; Quantità: -1173245088; Corsia: 32759; Prezzo -0.0005558
Codice: 120; Nome: Pringles; Quantità: 250; Corsia: 3; Prezzo 2.49
Codice: 121; Nome: Kinder Bueno; Quantità: 1000; Corsia: 1; Prezzo 1.79
Codice: 130; Nome: Twinkies; Quantità: 1300; Corsia: 1; Prezzo 1.49
Codice: 140; Nome: Mars; Quantità: 3000; Corsia: 1; Prezzo 2.79
Codice: 170; Nome: Pasta; Quantità: 150; Corsia: 2; Prezzo 0.79
```

Comment: `Articolo temp_list[this->size];` is only valid C++ if `size` is a compile time constant (e.g. declared `static const` or `constexpr` or a template parameter). Otherwise it is a so-called *variable length array (VLA)* and you rely on compiler extensions that not all actually do provide!

Comment: Any good reason you are not using `std::list` or probably even better `std::vector`? With the latter you could delegate sorting to the standard library: `std::sort` – which even sorts in O(n*log(n)) – as compared to your O(n²) variant...

Comment: Actually you could apply `std::sort` to your array, too: `std::sort(tmp_list, tmp_list + size, [](Articolo const& x, Articolo const& y) { /* compare x less to y */ })`... Well, for valid C++, you'd need to dynamically allocate the array (consider use of smart pointers!).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, the 'size' variable is indeed not a constant, thanks for your attention; sorry for not including minimal reproducible example, I really am new to this community, but are you suggesting that I am making the sorting mechanism more complicated than it should be?It seemed to me to be the easiest, but still, I didn't look it up or anything, I just tried to come up with one of my own.

Comment: @Aconagua I didn't use vectors or lists because I have to create my own functions for school homework, just to thoroughly understand the dynamics behind all of this

Comment: Easiest would probably be maintaining a sorted list right from the start (i.e. insert new elements at their corresponding sorting index)... You get that for free if you use a `std::map` or `std::set`, again with O(n*log(n)) for insertion of all n elements (compared to O(n²) with lists).

Comment: OK, you've been faster with your latest comment – then keep STL in mind for next time;)

Comment: Do you need to re-sort the list by multiple criteria or only by ID? Is it OK for you to modify internal representation upon sorting?

Comment: @Logu you should [edit] and show us a [MCVE] including simple input and expected output vs. actual output. Then people are more likely to answer your question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I edited and posted the structs I've been using, but I don't know what else to include to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Aconcagua I need to create a function that also sorts alphabetically

Comment: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`). And you should get used to implement the constructors initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`!): `Step(Articulo const& a) : info(a), next(nullptr) { }` – this prefers direct initialisation by value over default-initialisation + assignment, which can mean significant overhead for complex types. More important: Some types (references, const members, non-default constructable types, ...) *only* can be initialised that way...

Comment: OK, then you need indeed need to be able to resort... Is it OK for you to modify internal representation, i.e. modify the contained list itself? Recommendation, too: just implement one single sort function and pass different comparators as arguments to it (comparably to `std::sort`) – that way you won't duplicate code...

Comment: @Aconcagua By modifying the contained list are you suggesting to rearrange the values by just changing them instead of copying the elements and moving them?

Comment: @Aconcagua And also still, my problem is that the function leaves out the last element and when it does actually move it, it changes the values to nonsensical ones, as if I've put non-initialized variables into it

Comment: If you mean by 'values' the nodes then yes. You might then do an insertion sort, removing elements from beginning of the old list and inserting them at the right place within a newly created one (alternatively selection sort for largest one prepending them at new list) and finally only adjust the header from old to new list...

Comment: About sorting: You are not sorting correctly anyway – thus no need to care for the remaining element... Let's apply the same algorithm to integers – 4 1 3 2: When iterating you will start with lowest being 4, then discover 1 being smaller, thus you move it towards front, shifting 4 backwards: 1 4 3 2. However on continuing (j == 2, j == 3) you discover 1 <= 3 and 1 <= 2 thus no further shift. Your final 'sorted' order remains 1 4 3 2!

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if your function might produce uninitialised articles by itself. Are you sure that your list hasn't been corrupted already before? You might want to debug and inspect the list + the temporary list on every step to discover when the article in question gets corrupted.